# NOOBs Install. SD Card What File Format?

Tags: sd-card

Hi I've owned a Raspberry Pi for about 1 hours. I'm reading through the NOOBS install instructions (http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/). In the step "Format you SD Card" it says use some tool from some site on your Windows or MAC PC. I don't own a copy of either of those two operating systems. Anyway, I just want to know what file system can I format the SD Card as?! That is my question. *can use ext3|4 or some other format*?

Thanks,

P.S. There is a few other questions about formatting the SD Card, some mentioning `dd`. Others mentioning the Blah Associations Tool that only works with MAC/MS. All that is not relevant. I just want a straight answer about the allowed file formats for the SD Card.

Comment: What OS do you use, because if you are using Linux, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I don't think that is relevant to the question: "I just want to know what file system can I format the SD Card as?"

Comment: BTW this question is not a duplicate of "How do I install an OS image onto an SD card?" at all.

Comment: It is relevant, as you say you **don't own a copy of either OS**. Do you mean OS X/Windows or do you mean Raspbian/XBMC/Raspbmc/etc?

Comment: @RPi that was hyberbole on my part. Edited question to make it clearer what I am asking.

Answer (score 5):

For NOOBS, you should just format the SD card as fat32. NOOBs will take care of the rest of it for you.

The `dd` method is for "raw" Operating images that you can get off the Raspberry Foundation site, like Raspbian.
For those images, when you download the file, it will be in an `.img` format, which you then `dd` to the SD card like so - `dd if=raspbian-img-file.img of=/dev/sdx bs=1M` <-- where `/dev/sdx` is the device that corresponds to your SD Card.

Comment: OK Thanks Lawrence. Its funny, on the very next page of instructions for The NOOBS (http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md) it gives installation instructions again for some reason and says I should use FAT and parted which is exactly what I did. Looks like what ever the boot loader is its always looking for a fat filesystem in the first partition. Still interested ot know if it'll handle other file systems. Maybe I'll try later.